# Using a custom taxonomy for products shortcode in Woocommerce 3.3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, custom-taxonomy

I'm currently developing the homepage for a Woocommerce website and on this page the goal is to have 3 rows displaying products from different brands. Example; Row 1 will display Apple Products, Row 2 will display Samsung Products and Row three will display HTC products.

I've used the plugin CPT UI to create the custom taxonomy 'Brand'. Now I wish to use the example above to display only products listed under a particular brand.

Looking into the Woocommerce Shortcodes, I saw this:

```
[products limit="8" columns="4" category="hoodies, tshirts" cat_operator="AND"]
```

Is there away to do something like this with a custom taxonomy for this case brands? I.E:

```
[products limit="8" columns="4" brand="apple" cat_operator="AND"]
```

Any assistance or nudges in the right direction are much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible to extend Woocommerce `[products]` shortcode to To handle any  custom taxonomy like `"brand"` with some kind of trick.

The code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'extend_products_shortcode_to_brand', 10, 3 );
function extend_products_shortcode_to_brand( $query_args, $atts, $loop_name ){
    if ( ! empty($atts['class']) && strpos($atts['class'], 'brand') !== false ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $terms = array_map( 'sanitize_title', explode( ',', $atts['class'] ) );
        array_shift( $terms );
        $terms = implode(',', $terms);
        $terms = str_replace(",", "','", $terms);

        $ids = $wpdb->get_col( "
            SELECT DISTINCT tr.object_id
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships as tr
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
            WHERE tt.taxonomy LIKE 'brand' AND t.slug IN ('$terms')
        " );

        if ( ! empty( $ids ) ) {
            if ( 1 === count( $ids ) ) {
                $query_args['p'] = $ids[0];
            } else {
                $query_args['post__in'] = $ids;
            }
        }
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**USAGE**

We will use the `class` shortcode argument here:

**1) One Brand** - Displaying products from "Apple" brand:

```
[products limit="8" columns="4" class="brand,Apple"]
```

**2) multiple Brands** - Displaying products from "Apple" and "Samsung" brands:

```
[products limit="8" columns="4" class="brand,Apple,Samsung"]
```

> So the class `"brand"` is mandatory and needs to be the first one. Each term is coma separated.

Comment: Can this be used to exclude the brand products from the related products list

Comment: This doesnt seem to work anymore. I have a quite similair need, the taxonomy i created is "merk" and one of the brands i like to display is "Tenzo". But it doesnt work. Shortcode: [products limit="25" columns="5" class="merk,Rivsalt"]

Comment: It is still very much working in 2023. Don't forget to change the taxonomy title in the code, since is is hard coded.