# Add a custom field variable (ACF) to a custom Woocommerce shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

So I'm trying to get a variable to work within an echo do shortcode, however I can't seem to get it working. The goal is to be able to have the client select the brand the backend of the site using ACF instead of hard coding the brand selection.

Here is what I currently have:

```
<?php $brand_one_ids = get_field( 'brand_one' ); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[products limit="8" columns="4" class="brand,' . $brand_one_ids . '"]'); ?>
```

Any advice and fixes would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody could help you on this as you didn't explain in your question, that you:

- Have created a product custom taxonomy "Brand".
- Are using [**this answer code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50636718/using-a-custom-taxonomy-for-products-shortcode-in-woocommerce-3-3/50641610#50641610) to make it work on Woocommerce `[products]` shortcode
- That you want to display those "Brand" products in your home page

Your problem is just a settings problem in ACF. You need to enable those custom fields in your home page, this way:

[image]

Then you will get a custom metabox in your home page, with your "Brands" custom fields:

[image]

Once filled and saved, this time using the following code on your home, it will work:

```
<?php if( ! empty( get_field( 'brand_one' ) ) )
    echo do_shortcode( '[products limit="8" columns="4" class="brand,' . get_field( 'brand_one' ) . '"]'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, when I updated the fields it seems to have been delayed in updating the fields but everything works fine now.

Thanks again for the assistance!

I'll remember to post as much info as I can when asking a question.

Cheers!